# SSIS Script Task To Generate Error Output

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am attempting to parse a disaster of a text file.  It should have 24 columns in every row (CSV) but it does not.  I have to do some processing on the file, and I am using a script component with VB.Net to do so.  The code in the script component does a great job of parsing the good rows, but I would like to have it output the bad rows to a different flat file, and no luck.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
        Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then

        Dim strDQ As String = Chr(34) + Chr(34) + Chr(34)

        Dim strRow As String = Row.Column0.Replace(strDQ, Chr(34))


        Dim strColumns As String() = strRow.Split(CChar(","))

        If strColumns.Length <> 24 Then Exit Sub


        Output0Buffer.AddRow()
        Output0Buffer.Column = strColumns(0)
        Output0Buffer.Column1 = strColumns(1)
        Output0Buffer.Column2 = strColumns(2)
        Output0Buffer.Column3 = strColumns(3)
        Output0Buffer.Column4 = strColumns(4)
        Output0Buffer.Column5 = strColumns(5)
        Output0Buffer.Column6 = strColumns(6)
        Output0Buffer.Column7 = strColumns(7)
        Output0Buffer.Column8 = strColumns(8)
        Output0Buffer.Column9 = strColumns(9)
        Output0Buffer.Column10 = strColumns(10)
        Output0Buffer.Column11 = strColumns(11)
        Output0Buffer.Column12 = strColumns(12)
        Output0Buffer.Column13 = strColumns(13)
        Output0Buffer.Column14 = strColumns(14)
        Output0Buffer.Column15 = strColumns(15)
        Output0Buffer.Column16 = strColumns(16)
        Output0Buffer.Column17 = strColumns(17)
        Output0Buffer.Column18 = strColumns(18)
        Output0Buffer.Column19 = strColumns(19)
        Output0Buffer.Column20 = strColumns(20)
        Output0Buffer.Column21 = strColumns(21)
        Output0Buffer.Column22 = strColumns(22)
        Output0Buffer.Column23 = strColumns(23)

    Else
        Row.DirectRowToOutput1()


    End If

End Sub
```

I have spent an hour or so playing with the ExclusionGroup and Synchronious Output settings in the script component, but have not been successful.  Any assistance you all can render would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Error was in one of the If statements -- I need to process the row instead of exiting sub.  Works now.  Sorry!